# Remove assoc array from query string

Tags: javascript, urlsearchparams

I like to remove an array variable `conditions` from a query `string` which will be `window.location.search`.

- First output `Before` is the initial string.
- Second is after removing `sub`
- Third still contains `conditions`.

How can I get rid of it?

*edit*
The unencoded string is

```
conditions[0][0][field]=firstname&conditions[0][0][operator]=is&conditions[0][0][value]=John&conditions[1][0][field]=lastname&conditions[1][0][operator]=is&conditions[1][0][value]=Doe
```

which is needed for the application.

```js
var string = '?page=foo&sub=bar&conditions%5B0%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=firstname&conditions%5B0%5D%5B0%5D%5Boperator%5D=is&conditions%5B0%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=John&conditions%5B1%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=lastname&conditions%5B1%5D%5B0%5D%5Boperator%5D=is&conditions%5B1%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=Doe';
var params = new URLSearchParams(string);

console.log('Before', params.toString());

params.delete('sub');

console.log('remove sub works', params.toString());

params.delete('conditions');

console.log('conditions still exist', params.toString());
```

Comment: should be an `=` after `conditions` in the URL.

Comment: You don't have a parameter named `conditions` in your URL - not from the JS perspective. What you have, is parameters named `conditions[0][0][field]`, `conditions[0][0][operator]`, etc.

Comment: it's an assoc array

Comment: ok so I need a custom method to remove all `conditions`?

Comment: It's only an array from say, for example, PHP's perspective, when it parse this kind of query string. But to JS, these are all just differently named parameters. Guess you could do something like loop over all entries, and then check if the key starts with `conditions` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this?

```js
var string =
  "?page=foo&sub=bar&conditions%5B0%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=firstname&conditions%5B0%5D%5B0%5D%5Boperator%5D=is&conditions%5B0%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=John&conditions%5B1%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=lastname&conditions%5B1%5D%5B0%5D%5Boperator%5D=is&conditions%5B1%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=Doe";
const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(string);

const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());

console.log({ params });

function getFilteredParams(params, filteredString) {
  let obj = {};
  for (const key in params) {
    if (key.indexOf(filteredString) == -1) {
      obj[key] = params[key];
    }
  }
  return obj;
}

console.log(getFilteredParams(params, "conditions"));
```

Comment: `page` and `sub` are subject to change/missing/unknown. I really like to just to get rid of the `conditions`

Comment: Thanks for the code, this brings me in the right direction.